# How to assert if the response code has only numbers?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I tried using a regex for numbers only but it didn't work.

Blow snapshot shows my configuration. i tried various combinations like contains, matches etc. [image: response assertion]

Answer (score 0):

There is `\d` character class which stands for digits.

As per [HTTP protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6)

> The status-code element is a **three-digit integer code** giving the
> result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request.

So you might want to additionally check the response to contain exactly 3 digits, the resulting regular expression would be something like:

```
\d{3}
```

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expresssions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for numbers:

- For 1 to 3 digits: `"^\d{1,3}$"`
- For 3 digits: `"^\d{3}$"`

To do proper Assertion never user regex pattern in Response code.

If you want to assert success code: use only `200` as Response code
For more precision, use any constant text from your Response code (i.e. a text in your response which will never change)

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression:

> [0-9]+?

And in Patterns matching rules,  check Equals instead of Contains